# How to change only frontend language in Cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, locale, frontend, multilingual

I have created multilingual website in English and Danish language using I18N and .po file. But if I change the language using I18n::locale() it changes the language of admin panel too. I want to change the language of frontend only. Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you tell us how you differ public actions with admin actions? do you use prefix for example !,

Answer (score 3):

Changing the locale the way you're doing it is correct:

```
I18n::locale('da_DK');
```

But if it's changing it in your admin panel too, then the question is purely about how your application is structured and where you are changing the locale.

If you set the locale in `AppController` for example, then it's going to change for all controllers. There are many ways you could do it. You could create an `AdminController` which handles an `/admin` prefix, and changes the locale just for that prefix.

```
    namespace App\Controller\Admin;

    use App\Controller\AppController;
    use Cake\Event\Event;
    use Cake\I18n\I18n;

    /**
     * Application Controller for `admin` prefixed controllers.
     * 
     * All controllers within the `app/Controller/Admin` directory should extend this
     * controller rather than the normal `AppController`.
     */
    class AdminController extends AppController
    {

        public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
        {
            parent::beforeFilter($event);

            I18n::locale('en_GB');
        }
    }
```

Then ensure you have correctly set up a prefix route for `/admin` so that you can put all your admin controllers in `app/Controller/Admin`, and all those controllers should extend `AdminController` instead of `AppController`.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to change the flow of my website. So I used 18n::locale('en_GB') in my all front-end controllers. That resolved my problem.